# Format a date using the %f %s (I think Java 7 formatter) type notation

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am using Spring Batch to output my domain object to a CSV file. To do this I am making use of a `FormatterLineAggregator`. It uses the `%s %f` type formats.

See below.

```
FormatterLineAggregator<MasterList> lineAggregator = new FormatterLineAggregator<>();
lineAggregator.setFormat("%s,%.2f,%.2f,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s");
```

This code is formatting my object into this line in my CSV.

```
A,100.00,100.00,Country Road Shirt,Promotion Component Name A,wasnow,On Sale,100,100 / 1000,2016-07-24,2016-07-24
```

I am really unfamiliar with the `%s %f` notation.

I want my dates on the end of that line to look like `dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss` instead they are `yyyy-mm-dd`.

How can I do that using this notation?

Also does anyone know where I can find a reference explaining the syntax more?

Comment: Does your date field's type is String or Date?

Comment: It's a java.util.date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class exist since Java 1.5.0.
You can use the below format to format your date.

```
%te/%<tm/%<tY %<tT

'e'     Day of month, formatted as two digits, i.e. 1 - 31. 
'm'     Month, formatted as two digits with leading zeros as necessary, i.e. 01 - 13
'Y'     Year, formatted as at least four digits with leading zeros as necessary, e.g. 0092 equals 92 CE for the Gregorian calendar.
'T'     Time formatted for the 24-hour clock as "%tH:%tM:%tS".
```

Here we reference arguments by position is to use the '<' ('\u003c') flag, which causes the argument for the previous format specifier to be re-used.

Example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb, Locale.US);
formatter.format("%s,%.2f,%.2f,%s,%s,%s,%s,%d,%s,%te/%<tm/%<tY %<tT,%te/%<tm/%<tY %<tT","A",11.2,12.3,"Country Road Shirt","Promotion Component Name A","wasnow","On Sale",100,"100 / 1000",new Date(),new Date());
System.out.println(sb);
```

Output:

> A,11.20,12.30,Country Road Shirt,Promotion Component Name A,wasnow,On Sale,     100,100 / 1000,25/07/2016  11:10:47,25/07/2016   11:10:47

Here is the code in [ideone](http://ideone.com/FedKyy)

For more information you can refer Java Doc [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Comment: I tried that and I get java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: e != java.lang.String
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printDateTime(Formatter.java:2835) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2740) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2526) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
 at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2981) ~[na:1.8.0_91]

Comment: I just about got it to work with argument index. There is just one small problem. I'e added an edit above.

Comment: Check my code in ideone. d is for  integral type . If it is integer then the result is formatted as a decimal integer.

Comment: thank you. Why did you use argument index for the dates only?

Comment: You are welcome.I have removed the index. Please have a look